# Yii CHtml::ajaxLink confirm javascript message on delete

Tags: php, yii

in my site i use CHtml::ajaxLink   it works fine form me and delete what i need
but i want to show javascript confirmation message with this option can any one help me

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('X',Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/deleteimg'),
                     array(
'type'=>'POST',
'data'=> 'js:{"data":'.$img->id.'}',       
'success'=>'js:function(string){ document.getElementById("'.$img->id.'").remove(); }'           
),array('class'=>'btn btn-danger small-btn'));
?>
```

Comment: if you're on Yii 2 and using GridView, confirmation on deletion is actually happening automatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add confirm in the `htmlOptions` array. Take a look:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('X',Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/deleteimg'),
 array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'data'=> 'js:{"data":'.$img->id.'}',       
    'success'=>'js:function(string){ document.getElementById("'.$img->id.'").remove(); }'           
),array(
    'class'=>'btn btn-danger small-btn',
    'confirm'=>'Are you sure?' //Confirmation
    ));
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Add it as another line (function) to the success function. This should normally work:

```php
echo CHtml::ajaxLink('X',Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/deleteimg'), array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'data'=> 'js:{"data":'.$img->id.'}',       
    'success'=>'js:function(string){ 
        document.getElementById("'.$img->id.'").remove();
        alert("Image deleted!"); }' // this is the line I added             
),
array(
    'class'=>'btn btn-danger small-btn'
));
```

Comment: i know it will work but i need confirm message if he insert yes i will delete this image that's i want

Comment: sorry, your question was very unclear... do you actually want to display a javascript `confirm` dialog and only delete if the user choses 'OK'?